# React - How to access props without using constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, eslint

Note: I encounter this specific problem using React Native, but I guess this goes for React in general as well.

I have a react component built using React.Component. 
I don't need to set state, but I do have props. My proposed syntax was as follows:

```
class Header extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.title}</div>;
  }
}
```

I understand I can use a function to construct this component, like this:

```
const Header = (props) => {
  return <div>{props.title}</div>;
}
```

But I prefer the former, because my component will grow, might have state etc, and I just want to keep all my components built in a similar fashion.

Now, my linter complains about having a useless constructor, but how else do I access the props while keeping a class constructor instead of a function constructor?

Comment: Without adding a constructor you can stil use `this.props` in your components. It is not a must.

Comment: have you just tried to remove constructor?

Comment: Wow. That works. But why, then, have I been doing super(props) for two years now... Is `super(props)` only required if you are creating a constructor for initialising state?

Comment: Remove the constructor for now. You can later put that in when you start using `state`

Comment: The constructor is called by React directly after the class is instantiated. It is  only necessary if you wish to execute at that point in time, such as setting initial state. You need to call super(props) if you want to interact with the props 'in the constructor'.

Comment: BTW, you don't need a constructor to set initial state, just initialize the state as class field declaration `state = {}` take a look [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-without-constructor)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> If you want to use this.props in the constructor, you need to pass props to super. Otherwise, it doesn't matter because React sets .props on the instance from the outside immediately after calling the constructor.

So just simply remove constructor() if useless

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer and for all of the comments. I just never realised that props were in scope of the class component from the start...

Answer (score 4):

you can access props without constructor in a class using "this", like this:

```
class XXXXXX extends React.Component {
   render() {
       return (
          <div>{this.props.value}</div>
       )
   }
}
```