# React native: how can i pass value in my custom component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i want to pass my params value in my custom component so below is my code

**Header.js**

```
class Header extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}


render() {
    return (
        <View >
        <Text >Title</Text>
        <Text>subtitle</Text>
        </View>
    );
   }

 }
```

I call my Header.js from my **main.js**

```
class Main extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}


render() {
    return (
        <Header title = {this.props.navigation.state.params.screen_title} subtitle= {this.props.navigation.state.params.subtitle} />
    );
    }

 }
```

I pass my title and subtitle in my header component , i just wanted to  know how can i access my passing variable value in my header component ? your all suggestions are appreciable

Comment: If you inject one component inside another, your case is not related to react-navigation. The only thing you need to use props. So react-navigation tag is irrelevant for your case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - How to access props without using constuctor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46836196/react-how-to-access-props-without-using-constuctor)

Answer (score 4):

Its very simple You can access it by

```
this.props.title
this.props.subTitle
this.props.nameOfTheProps
```